# SPARQL MIN on string

Tags: sparql

I am studying SPARQL and there is this example on the documentation page:

```
PREFIX : <http://people.example/>
PREFIX : <http://people.example/>
SELECT ?y ?minName
WHERE {
  :alice :knows ?y .
  {
    SELECT ?y (MIN(?name) AS ?minName)
    WHERE {
      ?y :name ?name .
    } GROUP BY ?y
  }
}
```

From this dabase:

```
@prefix : <http://people.example/> .

:alice :name "Alice", "Alice Foo", "A. Foo" .
:alice :knows :bob, :carol .
:bob :name "Bob", "Bob Bar", "B. Bar" .
:carol :name "Carol", "Carol Baz", "C. Baz" .
```

There is says that this query:

> Return a name (the one with the lowest sort order) for all the people that know Alice and have a name.

and the output is:

```
y   minName
:bob    "B. Bar"
:carol  "C. Baz"
```

But I can't understand how "B. Bar" is smaller than "Bob", for example. I cannot understand what the docs means with "lowest sort order". For me the output should be:

```
   y    minName
    :bob    "Bob"
    :carol  "Carol"
```

Comment: `min` does not mean the length of the string, it's Lexicographical order based. If you want the shortest string, use `MIN(strlen(?name))` to get the min length in a sub query, then select one name with this length

Comment: In fact I wanted to understand why "B. Bar" is before  "Bob", but then "." is before "O "in Sparql. Got it. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ascii/info, https://w.wiki/Dkn

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira ok, got it. Regarding *""." is before "O "in Sparql"* it's not only in SPARQL the case. It's just character encoding